# JAX-RS and Camel - Except 1st QueryParameter all others are null

Tags: java, jax-rs, apache-camel, cxfrs

For some reason, the second and the subsequent Query Parameters are just null.  The first one works perfectly fine.  I am using Camel+JAX-RS (CXF). This is just a GET request. The URL I am using is

`http://localhost:8181/cxf/coreservices/search?q=health&start=100&size=924`

**Here is my Interface declaration**

@Path("search")
public interface SearchRestService {

```
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public String searchGet(@QueryParam ("q") String q, @DefaultValue("0") @QueryParam("start") String start, @DefaultValue("10") @QueryParam("size") String size );
```

**Implementation**

```
public SearchResult<WikiSearchHit> searchGet(String q, String start, String size){

    logger.info("Inside wiki GET method: " +q + " start:"+start + " size:"+ size);
```

The `q` parameter comes in fine as `health` but the start and the size parameters are just null. Surprisingly, the default values aren't getting picked up too.

I am afraid I am doing something wrong in my camel routing.

**Router**

```
@Override
public void configure() throws Exception {

    from("cxfrs://bean://rsServer?bindingStyle=SimpleConsumer")
            .multicast()
            .parallelProcessing()
            .aggregationStrategy(new CoreSearchResponseAggregator())
            .beanRef("searchRestServiceImpl", "searchGet")
             ...
```

Thanks for your time :-)

Answer (score 0):

The Camel team is working on fixing this issue in the near future.  Until then use the following workaround.

You could get the entire query string as follows

String query = exchange.getIn().getHeader(Exchange.HTTP_QUERY, String.class);

//would return something like : q=health&start=100&size=924

**Interface**

```
@GET 
@Path("search") 
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON) 
public String searchGet();
```

**Implementation - Target method**

```
public SearchResult<WikiSearchHit> wikiGet(Exchange exchange){

        String q = exchange.getIn().getHeader("q", String.class); 
        String size = exchange.getIn().getHeader("size", String.class); 
        String start = exchange.getIn().getHeader("start", String.class);
```

**Router**

```
public class RestToBeanRouter extends RouteBuilder { 

    @Override 
    public void configure() throws Exception { 

        from("cxfrs://bean://rsServer?bindingStyle=SimpleConsumer") 
                .process(new ParameterProcessor()) 
                .removeHeaders("CamelHttp*") 
                .multicast() 
                .parallelProcessing() 
                .aggregationStrategy(new CoreSearchResponseAggregator()) 
                .beanRef("searchRestServiceImpl", "wikiGet") 
                .... 
                .end() 
                .marshal().json(JsonLibrary.Jackson); 
        //.to("log://camelLogger?level=TRACE"); 

    } 


    class ParameterProcessor implements Processor { 
        @Override 
        public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception { 

            Map<String, String> stringStringMap = convertQueryStringAsMap(exchange.getIn().getHeader(Exchange.HTTP_QUERY, String.class)); 

            //System.out.println("stringStringMap = " + stringStringMap); 

            for (Map.Entry<String, String> eachParamEntry : stringStringMap.entrySet()) { 
                exchange.getIn().setHeader(eachParamEntry.getKey(), eachParamEntry.getValue()); 
            } 
        } 


        private Map<String,String> convertQueryStringAsMap(String queryString){ 

            //some Guava magic 
            return Splitter.on("&").omitEmptyStrings().trimResults().withKeyValueSeparator("=").split(queryString); 

        } 

    } 
}
```

More details here : 
http://camel.465427.n5.nabble.com/JAX-RS-and-Camel-Except-1st-QueryParameter-all-others-are-null-tt5742470.html